# Must an unused function in a template class be valid?

Tags: c++

In a template I have some functions which are only valid for certain template types. GCC seems to be happy with this, but I'm not sure it is valid. Unlike typical SFINAE the function itself is not a template.

```
template<typename T>
struct generic {
  T item;
  void get_limited() {
    item.limited();
  }
};
```

Provided I don't call `get_limited`, is it okay to instantiate this class with a type that does not implement `limited`?

If no, how can I solve this?  I have a generic container class where certain features are enabled based on the allocate it is storing (so not directly on the type as above, but still a template parameter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template functions are instantiated on demand, so if there is no use of the function it need not be correct, at least for some possible instantiations. The standard does state that if a template is not valid for *any* instantiating type, the program is ill-formed (although the compiler is not required to diagnose it) even if it is never instantiated.

This feature is used in the standard library in different parts, where the requirements of a single function might be stricter than the general requirements that the template places on the instantiating types. For example, in the case of `std::map`, in general, the value type does not need to be default constructible, but if you want to use `operator[]` then it needs to be, since that operator might need to create an empty element if the key is not present.

Comment: *Subtle/pedantic*: For implicit instantiation, the *definition* of the member function is instantiated on demand. So, if the declaration/signature of the function contains an error (e.g. `decltype(item.limited()) get_limited();`), instantiating the class template will also fail.

Comment: This is an example of something that can be solved using either [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) or [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static_assert).

Comment: @DyP: Correct. The signature of the function is part of the *definition* of the class, not the member.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Neither SFINAE nor static_assert are golden hammers and they serve very different purposes. It is unclear what you would like *solved* with these tools, but I am a bit worried that they have become some kind of fuzz word in current C++ parlance. The example DyP talks about is `template <typename T> class X{ delctype(T::f()) f() { return T::f(); } };` (if I understood him correctly) and neither `static_assert` nor SFINAE are the correct tool to make that compile.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas lol I was just writing up a long question to ask about what is the "right" way to do things. From what I understand SFINAE with enable_if could make it compile, while static_assert will make it compile iff that function is not used (but I have to play around with it some more)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: The first step is providing a clear description of what you want/need.